# Hashing implementation of Dictionary, C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash

I have been trying to fully implement my hashing table, but I don't really understand exactly how the code works. I have my header file setup fine, I am just missing implementing the following:

`V * find(K key)` - which I want to return a pointer to the value I am looking for, or null obviously.

`bool addOrMod(K key, V val)` - which adds a new element, returning the status (true or false) for if the value is added.

`int size()` - which simply returns how many items are in my Dictionary.

I also think I didn't initialize SZ correctly in `int hash(string s)`

I appreciate your help.

Here is my class:

```
#include "Dic.h"
#include <string>

int Dic::hash(K key){       //DEPENDS ON K. This one assumes K is string
    return -1;  //stub code
}

void Dic::deallocate(){     //separate member called by destruc and op=
    for(int i=0; i<SZ; i++){
        //get rid of chain i
        DicNode * p = table[i];
        while(p!=0){
            DicNode * kill = p;
            p = p->nxt;
            delete kill;
        }
    }
    delete []  table;
}

V * find(K) {

    return *location;
}

bool addOrMod(K, V){

    return added;
}

int size(){

    return size;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

//BIG 3

Dic::Dic() {

}

int hash(string s) {
    int ret=0;
    int SZ = s.length();
    for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {
        ret+=s[i]-'A';
    }
    return ret%SZ;
}

Dic::~Dic(){this->deallocate();}

Dic::Dic( const Dic & src ){  //copy con
    *this = src;   //Uses operator= defined for Dic
}

Dic & Dic::operator=( const Dic & rhs ){  //assignment op
    if(this == &rhs){ cout<<"goofy"<<endl; return *this; }

    // clean up any memory allocated by this
    this->deallocate();
    // initialize this n,SZ,table to be like rhs
    this->n=rhs.n; this->SZ = rhs.SZ; this->table=new DicNode*[SZ];
    // duplicate the DicNode chains
    for(int i=0;i<SZ;i++){
        DicNode * q = rhs.table[i];
        if(q==0){
            this->table[i]=0;
        }else{
            this->table[i]=new DicNode;    //note: NOT DicNode()
            DicNode * p = this->table[i];
            while(true){  //loop inv: *p is blank node corresp to *q
                p->key = q->key;  p->val = q->val;
                if(q->nxt==0)break;
                q=q->nxt; p->nxt=new DicNode; p=p->nxt;
            }
            p->nxt=0;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Post your question on : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, it fits that website better

Comment: So it does, apologies!

Comment: @Drax: Please do not ask people to post non working code on codereview. This is off topic for the code review site which only reviews **Working** code. Broken code and specific questions on it belong on SO. You should have asked OP to refine his question and ask about a specific problem.

Comment: @LokiAstari My bad, didn't know it was limited to already working code.